# addEventListener is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer

Below javascript function uploads the chosen file and updates the grid. Its working perfectly in firefox but not in IE11. 
Observed that its not executing "ESignature/Registration" function in addEventListener. I kept break point at Registration function. Its not getting hit and not refreshing the grid. Please guide me to fix this problem

```
     $("#lnkAddAttachment").click(function (e) {
        if (document.getElementById("txtFile").files[0] != null) {
            oFiles = document.getElementById("txtFile").files[0];
            nFiles = oFiles.size;

            var selectedFile = document.getElementById("txtFile").files[0];

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var fd = new FormData();
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/getFile";

            fd.append("file", document.getElementById('txtFile').files[0]);
            $("#loadingwrapper").fadeIn();
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.send(fd);
            xhr.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/Registration";
                $('#gridAttachments').load(url + ' #gridAttachments');
                $("#loadingwrapper").fadeOut();
            }, false);
            $('#txtDescription').val('');
            $('#txtFile').val('');

            return false;
        } 
    });
```

Comment: First of all, why aren't you using `onreadystatechange` instead, and secondly why aren't you using jQuery for the ajax request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed url as below. it worked. Problem is whenever below url hits IE, it takes from cache and it won't hit Registration function. To make the url unique every time, added new variable called check to url. Its value will be unique everytime and hits Registration function.

```
var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/Registration?check=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Complete code:

```
$("#lnkAddAttachment").click(function (e) {
    if (document.getElementById("txtFile").files[0] != null) {
        oFiles = document.getElementById("txtFile").files[0];
        nFiles = oFiles.size;

        var selectedFile = document.getElementById("txtFile").files[0];

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var fd = new FormData();
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/getFile";

        fd.append("file", document.getElementById('txtFile').files[0]);
        $("#loadingwrapper").fadeIn();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.send(fd);
        xhr.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/Registration?check=" + new Date().getTime();
            $('#gridAttachments').load(url + ' #gridAttachments');
            $("#loadingwrapper").fadeOut();
        }, false);
        $('#txtDescription').val('');
        $('#txtFile').val('');

        return false;
    } 
});
```

Thank you T.J. Crowder and Chris for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

As you're clearly using jQuery already, I'd suggest using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) rather than using `XMLHttpRequest` directly, which would almost certainly solve the problem.

But if you want to keep using `XMLHttpRequest` directly for some reason, you most likely need to use `readystatechange` rather than `load`; perhaps IE11 doesn't support `load`, or doesn't support it in whatever compatibility setting it decided to use for your page. If your page is being loaded in some older compatibility mode, it also won't have `addEventListener` on the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

As you're not sharing the `XMLHttpRequest` instance with anyone, the simple way to deal with both of those potential problems is:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readystate === 4) { // Also consider checking `status`
        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/Registration";
        $('#gridAttachments').load(url + ' #gridAttachments');
        $("#loadingwrapper").fadeOut();
    }
};
```

And as [Chris points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29212390/157247), move that **above** the call to `.send`.

But again: You're using a library that handles these things for you. Use it.

Comment: I replaced addEventListener function with onreadystatechange as below. Still Registration function is not getting hit.xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {                     
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {                        
                        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "ESignature/Registration";
                        $('#gridAttachments').load(url + ' #gridAttachments');
                        $("#loadingwrapper").fadeOut();
                    }
                };                          xhr.send(fd);

Comment: @lavanyab: Then I think it's fairly certain there's something wrong in code you're not showing in the question. For instance, I'd look to see what the `url` variable has in it **client-side** in the browser's built-in debugger. And just generally, single-step through the client-side code to understand what's happening where.

Comment: Surprisingly, its working when I open the Debugger by pressing F12 in IE. If I close it, again its not working. Something strange

Comment: @lavanyab: That tells you that something, somewhere else in the code is using `console`, which only exists in IE when the debugger is open, so if code uses it, it fails when the debugger is closed. Search the code, find all occurrences of `console`, and remove them (or put them inside an `if (typeof console != "undefined")` guard).

Answer (score 1):

The "addEventListener" method is supported in Firefox, but it may not be supported in IE. You'll need to use "onreadystatechange" to handle the event of completing the request. Also, you'll want to setup your "onreadystatechange" handler before calling "send"; otherwise it's possible the request to the server will finish before you setup the handler.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FXMLHttpRequest#Properties